# WP7: how to create background process?

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-process

It needs to create instant messenger application. 
Background thread should work under lock screen and after Home button is pressed.
As I see, it is possible and **IM+** (by SHAPE services) works the same way, but how it is possible?

Working under lock screen possible by creating DispatcherTimer, but how to make process alive after user press Home button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run a application in the background on Windows Phone. You can run it under the lock screen sure, but not in the background.

And Periodic Background Tasks won't suit your need, as they only run every 30 minutes, as a separate process.

So again, it's not possible to run a chat/IM application in the background.

Comment: But It is possible for IM+ app. Why it is not possible for me?

Comment: IM+ uses push notifications to notify user about new messages. It doesn't running when you deactivate it

Comment: Thanks Ku6opr, looks like using push notification is a solution.